# struct store user input data and qsort output

Tags: c

**Error sort_structs_time.** Program to use struct and qsort to acccept and store user input; firstname, lastname, country and time. Output should be sorted on time using qsort e.g.

**input**

BEKELE Tariku ETH 27:31.43

RUPP Galen USA 27:30.90

FARAH Mo GB 27:30.42

**output**

FARAH Mo GB 27:30.42

RUPP Galen USA 27:30.90

BEKELE Tariku ETH 27:31.43

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

struct olympics { 
    //char athlete[25];
    char fname[15];
    char lname[15];
    char country[5];
    float time;
};

/* qsort struct comparision function (time float field) */ 
int struct_cmp_by_time(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    struct olympics *ia = (struct olympics *)a;
    struct olympics *ib = (struct olympics *)b;
    return (int)(60.f*ia->time - 60.f*ib->time); 
}

/* struct array printing function */ 
void print_struct_array(struct olympics *array, size_t len) 
{ 
    size_t i;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++) 
        printf("%s %s %s \t %.2f\n", array[i].fname, array[i].lname, array[i].country, array[i].time);

    puts("****");
} 

/* sorting structs using qsort() */ 
void sort_structs_time(void) 
{ 
    struct olympics structs[] = {
        scanf("%s %s %s %.2f\n", fname, lname, country, &time)
    };

    size_t structs_len = sizeof(structs) / sizeof(struct olympics);

    puts("**** Athletes finishing time...");

    /* print original struct array */ 
    print_struct_array(structs, structs_len);

    /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
    qsort(structs, structs_len, sizeof(struct olympics), struct_cmp_by_time);

    /* print sorted struct array */ 
    print_struct_array(structs, structs_len);
} 


/* call to the function) */ 
int main() 
{ 
    /* run the function */
    sort_structs_time();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a very loose grasp of C's fundamentals. Please read some basic material on the language.

Comment: Your code to define the array of athletes and then read the values in is going to need major work.  The syntax you have is simply not the way you do it.  You should define the size of the array (3, for example); you should then loop over standard input.  Note that you read the time as a string containing a segmented number (minutes, seconds and fractions of a second) which must presumably be converted into a single number of seconds. You probably want a separate function to convert the time information you read into the number of seconds. (Note that times can be under 10 seconds or hours).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler for the detailed comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some changes in your `sort_structs_time` and `struct_cmp_by_time` functions.
It's obvious that you have not understood C structs and matrices, so do a revision on this topics.

```
int struct_cmp_by_time(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    struct olympics *ia = (struct olympics *)a;
    struct olympics *ib = (struct olympics *)b;

    if (ia->time < ib->time) return -1;
    else if (ia->time == ib->time) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) qsort documentation and have a look on the comparison function presented there.

```
void sort_structs_time() 
{ 
int i, ath_num;

struct olympics *ath_recs;

printf("For how many athletes do you want to insert their records? \n");
scanf("%d", &ath_num);

ath_recs = (struct olympics *) malloc(ath_num*sizeof(struct olympics));

printf("Please insert athletes records. \n");
printf("type a random string and press ENTER when you done. \n");
for(i = 0; i < ath_num; i++){
    scanf("%s %s %s %f\n", ath_recs[i].fname, ath_recs[i].lname, ath_recs[i].country, &ath_recs[i].time); 
//Don't put %.2f on scanf!!! 
//Also, note that the fname, lname, country and time are struct fields, 
//so you have to access them this way.
}


puts("**** Athletes finishing time...");

/* print original struct array */ 
print_struct_array(ath_recs, ath_num);

/* sort array using qsort function */ 
qsort(ath_recs, (size_t) ath_num, sizeof(struct olympics), struct_cmp_by_time);

/* print sorted struct array */ 
print_struct_array(ath_recs, ath_num);
}
```

There are other ways also to correct your code. I just find this easier to understand .

A better representation of time, imo, is as this:

```
struct time{
    int mins;
    int secs;
    int fsecs;
}
```

so you can print the time this way:

```
printf("%d:%d,%d\n", mins, secs, fsecs);
```

(You have to change the parts of your program related to time if you use this representation, i.e. the comparison function.)

Comment: Hey Kapoios, thanks a lot for explaining the code.. much appreciated